# Which one to use? Entity Framework Power Tools 4 or Entity Data Model Wizard

Tags: entity-framework

Should I be using the new 'Entity Data Model Wizard' for code first generation of an existing database, instead of the Entity Framework Power Tools Beta 4 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functionality of EF Power Tools was moved to EF tooling and made a bit more flexible (e.g. in EF Tools you can select which tables to reverse engineer which is not possible with PowerTools). Also Power Tools are Beta and AFAIK it will never RTM while EF Tools are officially supported.